# How to fetch UserTask completionTime in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

In RuntimeDataService there is no abstract method available to fetch task completion time, UserTaskInstanceDesc doesn't have any completion time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available for retrieving TASK_EVENT on task id, which has completiontime and other useful information.